# How to pass values between drag.start and drag.end in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parameter-passing, drag

I can't get d.startX and d.startY to show up with values in the .end() block (they're undefined). Any ideas what's going on?

```
    .call(d3.drag().on("start", function(d) {
        let coords = d3.pointer(event);
        let xPos = coords[0]
        let yPos = coords[1]
        d.startX = xPos
        d.startY = yPos
    }).on("end", function(d) {
        let coords2 = d3.pointer(event);
        let xPos2 = coords2[0]
        let yPos2 = coords2[1]
        console.log(d.startX) //shows up as undefined
        console.log(xPos2)
        console.log(yPos2)
```

Comment: `d` should be persisted between these parts, so if you want to preserve them, just assign them to different properties of `d`. For example `d.start = { x: d.startX, y: d.startY }` should allow you to access them in "end" as well

Answer (score 1):

You could set any value to the current event (for example, 'start' event) in the "this" reference. In the respective "end" function, you can grab your value.

```
.call(d3.drag().on("start", function(d) {
  let coords = d3.pointer(event);
  let xPos = coords[0]
  let yPos = coords[1]
  d.startX = xPos
  d.startY = yPos
  this._current = d;
}).on("end", function(d) {
  let coords2 = d3.pointer(event);
  let xPos2 = coords2[0]
  let yPos2 = coords2[1]
  console.log(this._current.startX) //Must show the value
  console.log(xPos2)
  console.log(yPos2)`
```

```js
var element = d3.select("#dargAbleRect");
var svg = d3.select("svg");

//append text to the svg
svg
  .append("text")
  .attr("font-size", 15)
  .attr("fill", "red")
  .attr("x", element.attr("x"))
  .attr("y", element.attr("y"))
  .text("drag me!");

// Event handlers
const clickElementEventHandler = function (event) {
  this._current = event;
  this._current.initPosition = {
    x: d3.select(this).attr("x"),
    y: d3.select(this).attr("y")
  };
  d3.select(this).attr("fill", "black");
};
const dragElementEventHandler = function (event) {
  d3.select(this).attr("x", event.x).attr("y", event.y);
  svg.select("text").text("dragging");
};
const dropElementEventHandler = function (event) {
  const { x, y } = this._current.initPosition;
  element.attr("fill", "red");
  svg.select("text").attr("x", x);
  svg.select("text").attr("y", y);
  svg.select("text").text(`I was here!! (X:${x},Y: ${y})`);
};

//bind Event Handlers to the element
element
  .attr("opacity", ".5")
  .call(
    d3
      .drag()
      .on("start", clickElementEventHandler)
      .on("drag", dragElementEventHandler)
      .on("end", dropElementEventHandler)
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <h3>Drop event for D3!!</h3>
      <svg width="400" height="400">
        <rect id="dargAbleRect" width="40px" height="40px" x="100" y="50" />
      </svg>
      <p></p>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```